# Service Account in SSRS 2019 Configuration

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have two questions please:

1. BOL tells me that Group Managed Service Accounts (gMSAs) are not supported as a report server service account. [BOL Reference - Configure the Report Server Service Account (Report Server Configuration Manager)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-the-report-server-service-account-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16)

however, some articles I've seen on the internet seem to be suggesting that more recent versions of SQL can use gMSAs even though BOL doesn't say that. Is this correct?

2. For the SQL instance in question, I have tried using the gMSA that both the Engine and Agent services run successfully under and I get  a similar error as I get when I use the built in Virtual Service Account. The error message is: Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. …   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.

Obviously for the gMSA the error message is with that account name.

My preference will be to use the gMSA if that is indeed supported for SQL 2019. However, if it is not supported then I can use the Virtual Service Account but how do I configure it to stop giving this error message? The account is mapped to the ReportServer database.

I will appreciate some help please. Thank you.

Comment: @JD thanks for editing, makes an easier read, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

> how do I configure it to stop giving this error message?

Create user in ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB, msdb databases and grant it [RSExecRole].
Also grant db_owner for ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB
and [SQLAgentOperatorRole],[SQLAgentReaderRole],[SQLAgentUserRole] for msdb.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and the response. I will try it out on Monday and feedback. However, could you kindly clarify, do you mean I am unable to use the Virtual Service account and I will need to create a new SQL Server account? Or do you mean I should grant those permissions to the virtual service account NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices? I would appreciate the clarification please. Thank you.

Comment: The account running SSRS (NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices or gMSAs) needs to have a user with permissions in ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB and msdb databases to bypass the error message you mentioned.

Comment: thank you again for your time and response. I have checked all those permissions and they all already exist as you listed. So the SSRS Configuration Manager must have granted all the required permissions as you rightly listed. A mystery however is that in spite of the failed login error message, the user actually currently has 5 successful connections to the Report Server database. I don't understand that . The entry in errorlog is that Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\SQLServerReportingServices'-Reason:Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: ::1]